# Android OS dialog Box Which shows Force Close and ok when Application remains in idle state for some Time

Tags: android

```
*
```

*
    My Problem is that each Activity in my App gets data from Web Service and if
        it remains idle for some OS dialog pops up showing Force Close and OK 
        option. when i clicks force close it stops but when i click Ok button it remains 
        in Activity, but when i move to other activity no data is shown as it does not hit web service
        to get data for that activity

```
    So, how to handle this situation 



        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.coupon_layout);
            context = this;
            merchantName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CouponsMerchantName);
            address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CouponsDetailAddress);
            phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CouponsDetailsPhone);
            categoryImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.CouponsCategoryImage01);
            couponsListLayout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CouponsListLayout);
            backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CouponsBackButton);

            backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            try {
                entry = Data.storeMecrchantDetailMain.get(0);

                merchantName.setText(entry.getMerchantName());
                address.setText(entry.getAddress());
                phone.setText(entry.getPhone());

                ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(CouponsActivity.this);
                String categoryImg = Data.URL_BASE + entry.getCategoryImg();
                categoryImage.setTag(categoryImg);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(categoryImg, CouponsActivity.this,
                        categoryImage);

                adapter = new CustomAdapterCoupons(this, entry.getCouponsList());
                couponsListLayout.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        class CustomAdapterCoupons extends BaseAdapter {
            /* Variable Declaration */
            private Context context;

            private List<CouponBean> list;

            private CouponBean entry;
            public com.a.util.ImageLoader imageLoader;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;

            public CustomAdapterCoupons(Context context, List<CouponBean> list) {
                this.context = context;
                this.list = list;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) CouponsActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                imageLoader = new com.abc.util.ImageLoader(context);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public class ViewHolder {
                public TextView couponName, couponCode, usageDescription,
                expirationDate;
                public ImageView couponImage;

            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ViewHolder holder = null;

                entry = list.get(position);

                if (convertView == null) {

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coupons_list_layout,
                            null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.couponName = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.CouponListCouponName);
                    holder.couponCode = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.CouponListCouponCode);
                    holder.expirationDate = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.CouponListDetailDate);
                    holder.usageDescription = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.CouponListUsageDescription);
                    holder.couponImage = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.CouponListLeftImage);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    // Set the display text
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.couponName.setText(entry.getCouponName());
                holder.expirationDate.setText(context
                        .getString(R.string.Coupon_Expiration_Date)
                        + "\n"
                        + entry.getExpirationDate());
                holder.usageDescription.setText(entry.getUsageDescription());
                holder.couponCode.setText(entry.getCouponCode());

                holder.couponImage.setTag(Data.URL_BASE_2 + entry.getCouponImage());
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(Data.URL_BASE_2 + entry.getCouponImage(),
                        (Activity) context, holder.couponImage);
                Log.v(Data.LOG3, "image" + entry.getCouponImage());

                final Button savedMyCoupons = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.CouponListAddtoMyCouponButton);
                if (entry.getSavedMyCoupons().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    savedMyCoupons.setText(context
                            .getString(R.string.Add_to_myCoupons));
                    savedMyCoupons.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done_btn);
                    savedMyCoupons.setTag(entry.getCouponId().toString());
                    savedMyCoupons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            createProgressDialog();

                            new Loader()
                            .execute(savedMyCoupons.getTag().toString());
                        }
                    });

                } else if (entry.getSavedMyCoupons().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    savedMyCoupons.setText(context
                            .getString(R.string.Already_Added_to_my_coupons));
                    savedMyCoupons.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    savedMyCoupons.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                }

                // display the view corresponding to data at specified position
                return convertView;

            }
        }

        private void createProgressDialog() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            // progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.Please_Wait);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.anim.simple_animation));
            progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.Please_Wait));
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            Log.v(Data.LOG, "On Resume");

            super.onResume();
        }

        class Loader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            Boolean value;

            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Data.URL_POST_DATA);
                    try {

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("couponsubmit",
                                "submit"));

                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid",
                                Data.GET_SESSION_ID));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api", "on"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("couponid",
                                arg0[0]));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                                responseHandler);
                        // String result = responseBody;
                        Log.v(Data.LOG1, "Response : " + responseBody);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(Data.LOG, "" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                LocateServices.getInstance().getStoreMerchantDetails(
                        entry.getMerchantID());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODOAuto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }

            private Handler handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    entry = Data.storeMecrchantDetailMain.get(0);
                    adapter = new CustomAdapterCoupons(context,
                            entry.getCouponsList());
                    couponsListLayout.setAdapter(adapter);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            };
        }
    }
 Thanks for any help.
```

*

- 

Comment: Are you doing the web service call on a seperate thread or on the UIThread? That is to say, is your data being pulled in the onCreate or a similar method? If so than that's likely your problem...

Comment: please do not copy the code with privacy conflicts for any app

Answer (score 0):

The dialog you are talking about is called ANR(Activity Not Responding) dialog, and there's no any method by which you can get the dialog to go away, and you should not try to remove it either.
You can however, call a new thread and run the methods to get data from web in that separate thread, instead of the UI thread.
Another method could be to start the fetching method after a second. The code example for this could be like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                //Your method to get data from web here
             }
         }, 1000); //delay in milliseconds
```

The above code will delay the fetching method by a second, so that the ANR dialog can be tricked away. However you should use a separate thread instead of this for better result.

Answer (score 0):

Do your fetching in the background, your users will be happy. I use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Async Task function

Declare the function using

```
new AsynBackground().execute(u);
```

and implement the function as follows

```
private class AsynBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 

{

@Override

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fetchDistancesFromGoogle(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

}
```